# AsyncValidator overwrites Validator

Tags: angular

Are there any reasons why adding a validator overwrites the existing async validator?

I use Angular 12 and addValidator() on formGroup. The docs say: "without affecting other validators."

As soon as I add the validator, async validator did not fire any more.

```
public testValidator(): AsyncValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
      return of({wrongAuthority: 123});
    }
  }

public authorityValidator(control: AbstractControl) {
   return {wrongAuthority: 12333};
}

this.form = this._fb.group({...}, { asyncValidators: this.testValidator()});

this.form.addValidators(this.authorityValidator);
this.form.updateValueAndValidity();
```

Comment: Not sure if this is your issue, but shouldn’t this be an array:  asyncValidators: this.testValidator() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Investigation of Angular code provide some results:

```
(this as {errors: ValidationErrors | null}).errors = this._runValidator();
(this as {status: FormControlStatus}).status = this._calculateStatus();

 if (this.status === VALID || this.status === PENDING) {
    this._runAsyncValidator(opts.emitEvent);
 }
```

As you can see sync validator executes first and sets the status of control then if he throws an error async validator is ignored by the value of status. That makes sense.

[Github](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/e49fc96ed33c26434a14b80487dd912d8c76cace/packages/forms/src/model.ts#L840)

P.S. [executing of validators with console.log](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mzkbe9?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: thanks! that solves my problem. Is there any way to run the async validator independent from status / every time?

Comment: @robert there is no sense, you can emulate validation logic manually by using valueChanges subscription and execute validator, but in my point of view, your flow is not a validation :)

Comment: why it makes no sense? for example, i have a group wide async validator....any nested sync validator will prevent the async one to execute. so I can't display the group wide error to the user

Comment: @robert okay, I agree with your case, so looks like the angular repository needs another one issue :)
so the solution for you is a subscription for valueChanges and manual set the errors.

Comment: how you would trigger the async validator via valueChanges?

Comment: @robert this.form.asyncValidator(this.form)